# Status Bar is white when entering immersive full screen mode

Tags: android, android-theme, android-fullscreen

I make a simple projet about immersive full screen mode according to [Using Immersive Full-Screen Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

But first of all it perfect fine when I select `Make Immersive` button, app is entering immersion fullscreen mode. 
[image: Perfect for First Time]

My problem is after selecting the `Cancel Immersive` button, and select `Make Immsersive` again. Although app is immersive mode, in the place of status bar is being white

[image: Status bar place is being white]

Here is my hide and show functions

```
private void hideSystemUI() {
        // Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
        // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
        View mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }

    private void showSystemUI() {
        View mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                         |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

and my `activity_main.xml` is

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.aungmyolwin.immsersivedelete.MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_immersive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="make immersive" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel_immersive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="cancle immersive" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_show_dialog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="show dialog" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this for temporary. Doing `requestLayout` after making fullscreen mode

Here is my codes

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

findViewById(android.R.id.content).requestLayout();
View mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

                mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

Answer (score 2):

make transparent the status bar in your theme

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

onCreate

```
Window window = getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = window.getAttributes();
winParams.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
window.setAttributes(winParams);

window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                     |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: notting change expect status bar color is white to grey bro

Comment: your code is right. But My Problems is to disappear status when entering immersive mode. Not Transparent . Thanks bro!